# File redirection fails in Bash script, but not Bash terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection

I am having a problem where cmd1 works, but not cmd2 in my Bash script ending in .sh. I have made the Bash script executable.

Additionally, I can execute cmd2 just fine from my Bash terminal. I have tried to make a minimally reproducible example, but my larger goal is to run a complicated executable with command line arguments and pass output to a file that may or may not exist (rather than displaying the output in the terminal).

Replacing > with >> also gives the same error in the script, but not the terminal.

My Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cmd1="cat test.txt"   
cmd2="cat test.txt > a" 
echo $cmd1   
$cmd1  
echo $cmd2   
$cmd2
```

test.txt has the words "dog" and "cat" on two separate lines without quotes.

Comment: Did you try to use `eval`? See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash and try in your script `eval $cmd1`and `eval $cmd2`

Comment: I cold try that. Eval has a reputation for vulnerability, but  program input will be controlled by a trusted user. I need to change the output location perhaps by passing a variable  ($outputFile) because I want to automate an executable with varying inputs and outputs. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Long answer: the shell expands variable references (like `$cmd1`) toward the end of the process of parsing a command line, *after* it's done parsing redirects (like `> a` is supposed to be) and quotes and escapes and... In fact, the only thing it does with the expanded value is word splitting (e.g. treating `cat test.txt > a` as "cat" followed by "test.txt", ">", and finally "a", rather than a single string) and wildcard expansion (e.g. if `$cmd` expanded to `cat *.txt`, it'd replace the `*.txt` part with a list of matching files). (And it skips word splitting and wildcard expansion if the variable is in double-quotes.)

Partly as a result of this, the best way to store commands in variables is: don't. That's not what they're for; variables are for data, not commands. What you should do instead, though, depends on *why* you were storing the command in a variable.

- If there's no real reason to store the command in a variable, then just use the command directly. For conditional redirects, just use a standard `if` statement:

  ```
  if [ -f a ]; then
      cat test.txt > a
  else
      cat test.txt
  fi
  ```
- If you need to define the command at one point, and use it later; or want to use the same command over and over without having to write it out in full each time, use a function:

  ```
  cmd2() {
      cat test.txt > a
  }
  cmd2
  ```
- It sounds like you may need to be able to define the command differently depending on some condition, you can actually do that with a function as well:

  ```
  if [ -f a ]; then
      cmd() {
          cat test.txt > a
      }
  else
      cmd() {
          cat test.txt
      }
  fi
  cmd
  ```
- Alternately, you can wrap the command (without redirect) in a function, then use a conditional to control whether it redirects:

  ```
  cmd() {
      cat test.txt
  }
  if [ -f a ]; then
      cmd > a
  else
      cmd
  fi
  ```
- It's also possible to wrap a conditional redirect into a function itself, then pipe output to it:

  ```
  maybe_redirect_to() {
      if [ -f "$1" ]; then
          cat > "$1"
      else
          cat
      fi
  }
  cat test.txt | maybe_redirect_to a
  ```

  (This creates an extra `cat` process that isn't really doing anything useful, but if it makes the script cleaner, I'd consider that worth it. In this particular case, you could minimize the stray `cat`s by using `maybe_redirect_to a < test.txt`.)
- As a last resort, you can store the command string in a variable, and use `eval` to parse it. `eval` basically re-runs the shell parsing process from the beginning, meaning that it'll recognize things like redirects in the string. But `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet, because it's easy for it to treat parts of the string you thought were just data as command syntax, which can cause some really weird (& dangerous) bugs.

  If you must use `eval`, at least double-quote the variable reference, so it runs through the parsing process just once, rather than sort-of-once-and-a-half as it would unquoted. Here's an example of what I mean:

  ```
  cmd3="echo '5 * 3 = 15'"
  eval "$cmd3"
  # prints: 5 * 3 = 15
  eval $cmd3
  # prints: 5 [list of files in the current directory] 3 = 15
  # ...unless there are any files with shell metacharacters in their names, in
  # which case something more complicated might happen.
  ```

[BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) discusses some other possible reasons and solutions. Note that the array approach will not work here, since arrays also get expanded after redirects are parsed.

Answer (score 1):

If you pop an 'eval' in front of $cmd2 it should work as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd2="cat test.txt > a"  
eval $cmd2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure about the operation of a script you could always use the debug mode to see if you can determine the error.

bash -x *scriptname*

This will run the command and display the output of variable evaluations. Hopefully this will reveal any issues with syntax.